# VC++ Colors in console

Tags: visual-c++, colors

I'am not a VC++ Dev but I'am searching to EDIT a source code. I want simply add new line on my Console with Different color (Green, Red ...)

```
void main()
{
    static char * DES_KEY = "!_a^Rc*|#][Ych$~'(M _!d4aUo^%${T!~}h*&X%";

    XStrDESUtil desUtil(DES_KEY);

    printf("Password: %s\n", desUtil.Decrypt("1a6a2dfd3e44b8a0b02a2b66c801821e").c_str());

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I've searched but all what I found is

```
  printf ("\033[34;01mBonjour\033[00m\n");
```

and those characters ... but it doesn't work for some reasons :(

Comment: Windows' console subsystem does not support ANSI escape codes; you'll need to use a Win32 API such as [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: hmm ok thank you :)
& How I can make desUtil.Decrypt , Decrypt a Text that is on a .txt file (First line)
which is on the same place of the .exe


ty

Answer (score 1):

Check out this header-only library that works for both, ANSI and Windows consoles:

https://github.com/tapio/rlutil

[image: compiled on windows]

```
rlutil::setColor(rlutil::GREEN);
rlutil::setColor(rlutil::RED);
```

should suffice

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can use the [Windows Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this, such as [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I have created a small free C++ template library (one header only) to wrap many of that functionality. Available at http://cppconlib.codeplex.com/.

[image]